# Point multiple ips to one server

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, squid

I'm trying to setup a squid proxy on an ubuntu server. I happen to have multiple ip addresses that I bought along with the vps. Is it possible for me to setup the 2 extra ip addresses to point to my ubuntu vps so that I can have multiple proxy ips?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is, just setup your `/etc/network/interfaces` correctly.

Comment: Hi @ondra how exactly would I do this?

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface for two ways how to do it. Safer way is to use aliases eth0:x.